Responder el contexto o responder al error?
En el sitio existen preguntas que resultan salirse de lo habitual, estas preguntas están normalmente relacionadas a Framework o sistemas pre-construidos o con un avance en el desarrollo, como shopify, wordpress, laravel, synfony... etc.
El escenario algo genérico es el siguiente:
El OP describe un contexto en donde su servidor Web XAMPP no cumple con los requisitos de la plataforma que desea implementar (incompatibilidad) y para agregar más detalles muestra un error relacionado a esa incompatibilidad.
Hay dos posibles respuesta dependiendo de cómo queramos abordar el problema:

Decirle que debe actualizar todo lo relacionado al Sistema (Framework).
Decirle como obtener la compatibilidad sin necesitar de Actualizar el sistema (modificar XAMPP).

El problema aquí es que:
Si se tratara de un proyecto que esta iniciado decirle que actualizar todo (opción 1) lo relacionado al sistema es correcto.
Pero si tomamos en cuenta el contexto en donde hay un framework o sistema pre-construido: la opción 1 puede ser nefasta … incluso imposible sabiendo que no es óptimo debido al avance del proyecto … en donde actualizar no garantiza la compatibilidad con la lógica de negocio, entonces la opción 2 conseguir la compatibilidad puede ser la opción correcta, algo que si se responde con experiencia, la cosas puede tardar minutos en resolverse, mientras que la opción A podría tomar Meses y un gran costo económico…
Entonces me pregunto que sería correcto contestar:
Responder al Error Implícito (del lenguaje).
o Responder tomando en cuenta el contexto (despliegue, requerimientos).

en el contexto de la pregunta que respondiste, como ya sabes, mi punto de vista es no responder por dos motivos: el primero es que la pregunta carece de clariada, es una pregunta de un reglon (tanto asi que el bot de la comunidad puso un comentario al respecto).

si alguien quiere saber que pregunta es es esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/622106/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

El segundo punto es que esa pregunta (el error en si), ha sido hecha multiples veces en stackoverflow es tanto asi que al buscarla salen muchas preguntas en los resultados y en las respuestas a esas preguntas se aborda la causa del error y las posibles soluciones

pero la respuesta generica no responde a la pregunta del usuario ... como hacer el despliegue de xnova

Aca no puedes tomar como argumento que sea un caso diferente porque el op escribio que el desplieque es en xnova y en las otras preguntas no. Si el error se presenta en nginx con php la CAUSA del problema es exactamente la misma (version de php incompatible) y por ende la solucion tiene el mismo enfoque: instalar una version de php compatible o usar una extencion diferente y ambos casos estan cubiertos en respuestas a otras preguntas con el mismo problema.

@clay la respuesta que sujieres es meterce a xnova y cambiar el codigo ... y eso no es viable en el contexto para deplegar un sistema existente ... te lo puedo asegura con la experiencia que tengo en 20 años viendo PHP nadie cuerdo va a tocar un desarrollo cuando la solucion es cambia de version de php o instalar la extencion ... y eso no lo especifica como hacerlo en tu respuesta que marcas como duplicado y no dice el por que ... hay que ser mas especifico con la gente nueva en el sitio con esas respuestas genericas que das no ayudas a la comunidad  ...

yo no estoy dando nunguna respuesta, esas dos respuestas las diste tu en tu respuesta en  el punto A y B.  Y la que puse como ejemplo de duplicado es una de las 22 preguntas duplicadas.

eso no es un duplicado  ya lo dijo aqui abajo un mod ... que tenga el mismo mensaje de error no lo hace un duplicado ni se resuelve igual por que estamos ante el despliegue de una plataforma ...

@clay que tu quieras ver la pregunta desde el angulo apropiado para cerrarala por ser duplicado, no quiere decir que los demas debamos aceptarla ...

Igual no quiero que me mal entiendas, yo no digo que tu respuesta sea mala o que no tenga calidad. Mis comentarios son respecto a que la pregunta no debio haber sido respondidad por que carece de calidad y muestra falta de esfuerzo por parte del op... y es un error comun ya documentado en stackoverflow

@clay Lamento decirte que aunque así sea... para mi cuenta con todo lo necesario para recibir una respuesta: 1. desconocimiento de la plataforma de desarrollo xampp, 2. no puede desarrollar si no despliega la plataforma 3 un contexto de que esta usando para hacerlo, 4. sabe que el problema no es el código, si no el requisito de la plataforma, es una pregunta que aunque no tenga la mejor redacción y el mejor título cuenta con todo lo necesario para recibir una respuesta.

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

por eso stackoverflow tiene votos y moderadores, tu estas de acuerdo en que es una pregunta valida y la respondes, mi opinion es distinta, que le vamos a hacer, depronto se llena de votos positivos o depronto no, esto no depende de nosotros sino de la comunidad.

pero al tu comentar esto en mi respuesta .... se considera bandalizar una respuesta ... si la pregunta no te agrada por que tienes que comentar esas cosas en las respuestas ... la descicion de si se responde o no es mia ... no de la comunidad ...

@clay respuesta eliminada para que este satisfecho ...

Diría que siempre hay que leer la pregunta, entender el contexto de la misma y, según sea la situación, elegir entre cerrar como duplicada, cuando existe una respuesta canónica a la pregunta (más adelante abundaré sobre esto) o responder si se trata de un caso particular (lo que en inglés se llamaría un corner case).
Como aquí no reinventamos la rueda, dejo algunas referencias a hilos en el meta general y en el meta de StackOverflow (en inglés) donde se ha hablado de preguntas y respuestas canónicas, duplicados, etc., por ejemplo:

What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?
What is a good way to look for a canonical answer to a frequently asked question?
Canonical answers for repeated questions
Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions
A canonical answer is not actually canonical; what to do? <-- esta, sobre todo
Questions on corner-cases, obscure usage - get downvoted immediately
How to handle question titles that end up being irrelevant corner-cases to the problem?

En estas discusiones enlazadas encontrarás más enlaces a otras discusiones y artículos en donde se abunda sobre el tema.
En ocasiones, tener este criterio requiere un elevado grado de expertís sobre el tema. Reflexionando sobre esto, por ejemplo, deberíamos votar para cerrar preguntas como duplicadas solo en las etiquetas dónde nuestro conocimiento es elevado. Lamentablemente, las colas de revisión y las medallas entregadas por cerrar preguntas nublan el criterio de algunos miembros de la comunidad.
Regresando al tema, creo que como programadores que somos todos, sabemos que podemos encontrar un mismo mensaje de error, por poner un ejemplo, en muchas situaciones distintas. Hay casos dónde la solución siempre es la misma, hay otros dónde la solución va a depender de cómo estamos llegando a esa situación.
En estos casos, en mi opinión, cada caso particular puede y debe ser planteado como una pregunta, con sus detalles y cada caso requiere una respuesta que tome en cuenta esos detalles para resolver la situación.
Esto, sin olvidar que hay preguntas que tienen respuestas canónicas y que, en la medida de lo posible, deberían cerrarse como duplicadas de la pregunta que tiene esa respuesta.
Estoy consciente que hay personas en la comunidad que piensan distinto y que probablemente vamos a seguir viendo cierres de preguntas incorrectos y votos negativos a preguntas y respuestas que tienen mérito propio.
Creo que lo que nos queda, es respetar su criterio y, también en lo posible, tratar de educar esos miembros de la comunidad para que logren ver lo valioso que es contar con estas preguntas/respuestas en contexto para cada uno.
Tomando como ejemplo tu respuesta a la pregunta Call to undefined function mysql_connect(), que supongo es la que da origen a tu pregunta, pienso que, como sugiere [esta respuesta], puedes:



If a question is really more specific than the title suggests, change the title to be more specific.

Si una pregunta es realmente más específica de lo que sugiere su título, cambiar el título para que sea más específico.


OJO que esto aplica tanto para la pregunta que estás respondiendo, como para la pregunta que pueden estar utilizando como un potencial destino de cierre por duplicación.
Sin olvidar que tenemos una plaga de preguntas mal planteadas en el sitio, la edición también puede incorporar información que haga falta en el propio contenido, por ejemplo, cosas que el AP haya dejado en comentarios o que, para el experto resulten evidentes, pero no para otros lectores y que valga la pena mencionar en la propia pregunta.

entiendo que la pregunta puede ser pobre para algunos, para mi contiene toda la informacion relevante y necesaria para poder ser respondida categoricamente las las opciones que resuelven el problema del despligue de xnova... pero la gente se esta enfocando en el error y no en el contexto ... resolver el contexto...  gracias por el aporte.

Creo que si, la pregunta es pobre, el AP deja claro su desconocimiento y también su falta de esfuerzo de investigación antes de llegar a SO, por eso no le doy un +1 y probablemente le de un -1. Sin embargo, creo que la pregunta está dentro del tópico del sitio y tiene todo lo necesario para responder, por eso no voto para cerrarla, pues no es lo mismo. Y creo que es un caso distinto al de otras que puedan tener el mismo mensaje de error o título. Creo también que merece una edición y, a menos que hubiera otra en el mismo caso, no tendría que ser cerrada como duplicada.

bueno pero ya la bandalizaron ... yo reporte esos mensajes y comentarios demas, que solo deshorientan a las personas de como funciona el sitio o como deberia de funcionar .. espero que algun Mod haga su magia ...

En mi opinión, no te han vandalizado. Vandalismo es  otra cosa y tachar lo que ha pasado de vandalismo es escalar a un conflicto que es innecesario. Diría que cada quién de los que participan busca el bien del sitio, de acuerdo a su criterio. Podemos discutir ese criterio, pero no veo nada constructivo en acusarnos unos a otros, sobre todo, poniendo un título negativo a acciones realizadas de buena fe.

yo no veo buena FE en querer manipular como la gente responde a las preguntas ... si la pregunta es mala es en lo que deberian enfocarce y no hacer estos comentarios , asumiendo una postura negativa como si tuviera la verdad absoluta en sus manos ...

OK, si no ves buena fe, está bien, ¿es suficiente para tachar de vandalismo esos comentarios? Mira, que no sos el único al que han hecho comentarios de ese tipo, a mi me intentó coaccionar un moderador diamantado para que respondiera solo lo que a él le gustaba... jaja :D

Eso está mal... ya elimine mi respuesta y esto es uno de los motivos por el cual la gente ya no quiere venir aquí a dar respuesta o interactuar... esta comunidad se está hiendo al caño. Que tengas buen día

Mi comentario, se da porque la pregunta en mi opinion es  pobre y aun cuando no sea un duplicado (que para mi lo es), responder a preguntas pobres es alentarlas. Las comparaciones son feas, pero stackoverflow espanol esta plagado de preguntas pobres en comparacion a su contraparte en ingles y si seguimos alentandolas cada vez va a ser peor. Solo como ejemplo algunas de estas preguntas cerradas en stackoverflow ingles estan mejor elaboradas que la pregunta en cuestion y aun asi fuera cerradas https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a1%20duplicate%3a0&searchOn=3

@clay ese es un argumento distinto y podemos charlarlo también, pero no es el argumento sobre el que se planteó la pregunta del AP ni mi respuesta. En general estoy de acuerdo en cerrar las preguntas mal hechas, excepto en casos especiales como las preguntas super básicas.

@Francisco, sugiero que consideres des-borrar tu respuesta. En mi opinión, es una buena respuesta y debiera quedar visible. Si la opinión de uno, que nunca pidió que la borraras te hizo hacerlo, espero que al calmarte, la opinión de otro miembro de la comunidad (yo) haga que lo re-consideres. Un saludo.

@Yussef, en lo personal, si alguien considera que yo soy conflictivo, nunca me lo ha dicho. Soy amable y firme en mis comentarios. Conozco las reglas, en líneas generales (es imposible saber todo). Como las conozco y tengo un criterio bien definido, no me afecta los comentarios que otros puedan expresar, en el sentido de sentir que me obligan a algo y creo que todos tienen derecho a sus opiniones. Pero yo actúo de buena fe y de acuerdo a mi conciencia y lo que, para mí, es el objetivo del sitio. No soy mayoría, tampoco suelo ser demasiado vocal con mis opiniones.

Eso no significa que sea cerrado. Trato de estar abierto a los argumentos de otros, adopto las cosas buenas y evalúo constantemente mi forma de actuar. Trato también de usar argumentos válidos y convincentes para defender mis posturas, pero no espero que alguién más actúe como yo. Mientras todos respetemos las reglas de convivencia, tenemos espacio para ser y algo bueno vamos dejando por el camino.

La comunidad no necesita mi respuesta y menos si la comunidad indica que la pregunta es duplicada... o no debe responderce, lo siento mucho por el usuario.
